# При поворачивании телефона(iphone) в горизонтальный вид, в safari, происходит сильное подёргивание текста в меню, либо высота блока, не понятно

Tags: iphone, safari

Вот [ссылка](https://optimapipe.ru/trouble_video.mp4) на видео, если вдруг кому-то встречалось такое поведение, помогите

Весь css код, соответственно можете посмотреть на сайте https://optimapipe.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается safari-mobile как-то не так понимал свойство transition, там между точками 768 и 576 есть изменение размера шрифта ссылки и каким-то образом оно отрабатывало и дергалось. Убрав transition всё устаканилось.